# How do I ignore empty string while using msgspec?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-dataclasses

I am using msgspec for serializing and validating my classes and I have such models

```
class Stop():    
    stop_code: Optional[int] = ''
```

and when I pass empty string, it fails saying expected null|int and got string instead. What is the  way that I can accept empty string and int.
Or what is the most performant way to convert empty string to none
Currently I am using this to ignore the empty string keys
`model = self._factory({k: row.pop(k).strip() for k in self._model_field_names_set if row[k].strip() != ""})`

Although I understand that i am accepting empty string in int field in this example, its a bit more complex in the actual implementation but the gist is that I want the actualy validation class or empty string would do

Comment: Why don't you simply use None as default value? Then it matches what you have written as type annotation and you don't have to convert anything.

Comment: You could annotate an empty string with `typing.Literal['']`.